# How to Convert a Object to Json query by elasticsearch

Tags: json, angular, typescript, elasticsearch

im working on a Search Application based on Angular7 and elasticsearchJS . In my data Service i create the elasticsearch json body query from User Inputs. It works well with a simple string query at this.query. It wont work for a complex array from this.selectedTopics ( my Checkboxes ).
The Output is destroyed in the JSON ( see Image )

[image]

i become backslashes in my console.log at my query (see image )

```
console.log(this.selectedTopics);

  // Output of selectedTopics is this:
  //  ["Lindenholz", "Sandstein"]

  this.selectedTopics.forEach( (item) => {
      this.termarray.push('{ "term": {"79_material":"' + item + '"}}');
  });

  console.log(this.termarray.join(', '));

    // Output of termarray is this:
    //
    //  [
    //      { "term": {"79_material":"Sandstein"}},
    //      { "term": {"79_material":"Lindenholz"}}
    //  ]
    // looks fine in console. But if i send the termarray to the json body it looks wrong with the backslashes.

  this.body = {
    // 'size': this.size.value, // document anzahl
    'size': '100',
    'from': '0', // page
    'query': {
      'filtered': {
        'query' : {
            'multi_match': {
                'query': this.query,
                'type': 'phrase_prefix',
                // 'fields': ['79_material', '79_technik'] // Fulltext or Category
                'fields': this.selectedCategory
            }
        },
        'filter': {
            'bool': {
                'must': [
                  this.termarray.join(', ')
                  // {'term' : { '79_material': 'holz' }},
                  // {'term' : { '79_material': 'lindenholz' }}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
    },
    // Faceten Auswahl hier und in der Searchlist. Auf content und keyword achten.
    'facets' : {
      '79_material' : {
        'terms' : {'field' : '79_material.keyword'}
     },
      '79_technik' : {
        'terms' : {'field' : '79_technik.keyword'}
    },
      '79_kuenstler' : {
        'terms' : {'field' : '79_kuenstler.content'} // neue Indexierung mit Keyword
    },
    '79_verortung' : {
      'terms' : {'field' : '79_verortung.content'} // neue Indexierung mit Keyword
  },
  },
    'sort' : [
      { '79_material' : {'order' : 'asc'}},
      '_score'
  ]
  };
```

[image]

The Result must be this:

```
[
{'term' : { '79_material': 'holz' }},
{'term' : { '79_material': 'lindenholz' }}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
this.termarray.push({ term: { '79_material': item }});
```

(alternatively:

```
this.termarray.push({ 'term': { '79_material': item }});
this.termarray.push({ 'term': { "79_material": item }});
this.termarray.push({ "term": { "79_material": item }});
```

)

**UPDATE**:

The description is not clear on how `termarray` is handled, but what if you just add the items directly to `body`:

```
let termarray = this.body.query.filter.bool.must;
this.selectedTopics.forEach( (item) => {
    termarray.push({ term: { '79_material': item }});
});
```

**UPDATE 2**:

Here is a screenshot from Chrome after applying UPDATE:

[image: screenshot]

Notice that when you apply `JSON.stringify(body)`, you get the expected output, i.e., no backslashes.

Comment: same problem. backslashes before every ' or " . if i change the quote logic from " to ' then it exports unicode. ```
                "{\"term\":{\"79_material\":\"Lindenholz\"}}",
                "{ \"term\": {\"79_material\":Lindenholz}}",
                "{\"term\":{\"79_material\":\"Sandstein\"}}",
                "{ \"term\": {\"79_material\":Sandstein}}" ```

Comment: See UPDATE on termarray.

Comment: Same Issue when i use it directly to the body. i have updated my Question for better understanding. thanks for helping

Comment: See UPDATE 2. No backslashes.

Comment: Just an additional comment that to me it seems that the problem is that you first have a JavaScript object that is translated to JSON string, and then that string is translated to JSON again, thus the backslashes. Instead, you should have all the data first as a JavaScript object (`this.body`), and then translate that object (once) to JSON.